# How Would I Generate A Value Based Off Of 4 Different Probabilities?

Tags: r

I am pretty new at R, but I know one thing it's big on is 1 line computations.

I have a variable and I want it to be one of four results based off of some probabilities. Is there a quick and easy way to calculate this?

```
A' && B 21%
A && B 27%
A && B' 3%
A' && B' 49%
```

I think I need to do something involving

```
runif()
```

But I'm not exactly sure what.

Comment: How new are you to statistics? Those probabilities do not sum to 1.0. Also unclear why you think that runif would be needed when your outcome is categorical.

Comment: Haha, I accidentally put 30% instead of 3. Thats my bad. I'm very new to R and am still unsure for the procedure for doing things the "right" way

Comment: Not really clear what you are asking. The function `sample()` has an optional argument `prob`. You can use it to choose elements from a discrete set with a specified vector of probabilities. Type `?sample` in the console for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to get random draws from categories is the `sample` function. This shows why it might be useful to set.seed to make code reproducible:

```
   > mysample <- sample( c("notA && B", "A && B", "A && notB", "notA && notB"), size=100, prob=c(.21, .27, .03, .49), replace=TRUE)
> table(mysample)
mysample
      A && B    notA && B notA && notB 
          34           21           45 
> mysample <- sample( c("notA && B", "A && B", "A && notB", "notA && notB"), size=100, prob=c(.21, .27, .03, .49), replace=TRUE)
> table(mysample)
mysample
      A && B    notA && B notA && notB 
          25           13           62 
> mysample <- sample( c("notA && B", "A && B", "A && notB", "notA && notB"), size=100, prob=c(.21, .27, .03, .49), replace=TRUE)
> table(mysample)
mysample
      A && B    A && notB    notA && B notA && notB 
          26            3           24           47
```

Better practice:

```
set.seed(123)
mysample <- sample( c("notA && B", "A && B", "A && notB", "notA && notB"), 
                    size=100, prob=c(.21, .27, .03, .49), replace=TRUE)
```

Result will be the same each time the two lines are run together.

```
> table(mysample)
mysample
      A && B    A && notB    notA && B notA && notB 
          23            2           22           53
```